React Hook "usePathname" cannot be called inside a callback
Am deploying my nextjs application to vercel but the process exits and throws. 28:26  Error: React Hook "usePathname" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks.
this is how my nav-links looks like
'use client';

import {
  UserGroupIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  DocumentDuplicateIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import clsx from 'clsx';

// Map of links to display in the side navigation.
// Depending on the size of the application, this would be stored in a database.
const links = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/dashboard', icon: HomeIcon },
  {
    name: 'Invoices',
    href: '/dashboard/invoices',
    icon: DocumentDuplicateIcon,
  },
  { name: 'Customers', href: '/dashboard/customers', icon: UserGroupIcon },
];

export default function NavLinks() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const isActiveLink = (href: string) => {
    return pathname === href;
  };

  // active= pathname === link.href
  return (
    <>
      {links.map((link) => {
  
        const LinkIcon = link.icon;
        const active = isActiveLink(link.href);
        return (
          <Link
          
            key={link.name}
            href={link.href}
            className={clsx(
              'flex h-[48px] grow items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-3 text-sm font-medium hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600 md:flex-none md:justify-start md:p-2 md:px-3',
              {
                'bg-sky-100 text-blue-600': active,
                // 'bg-sky-100 text-blue-600': pathname === link.href,
              },
            )}
            
          >
            <LinkIcon className="w-6" />
            <p className="hidden md:block">{link.name}</p>
          </Link>
          
        );
      })}


    </>
  );
}

I tried moving the activelink logic from the map function but it persistently throws the same error.
This application runs normally on localhost.

the usePathname() function is not in the good place, shifted higher like this:
export default function NavLinks() {
const pathname = usePathname();

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
